# How to split and estimate work in multi layer application

Tags: web-development, estimation, team

So, I'm trying to understand how this is done in real life... If I have a website with an API and a UI, and a User Story comes in like... *as a user I want to be able to login* that requires changes changes to both tiers and different teams work on each tier.

1. Would you create separate user stories for each team?
2. Do they estimate together the user story?
3. Do they branch out together o separately?

I don't know, what's kind of the processes you all follow?

Comment: Ask yourself this question: what value is there to the user if the UI team completes the work but there is no API for it to call? That should tell you where the boundary of the **user** story should be.

Answer (score 2):

The best estimates are done by the people doing the work. That would indicate that the best estimates for the API would come from the team creating or modifying the API and the best estimates for the UI would come from the team building the UI.

However, that's limited to this particular case. It's also a very ineffective structure, since you would need to invest time in defining the interface between the API and UI before either team could start their work and then perform integration testing and resolution of integration defects. It also says nothing about the ordering of work, so some coordination would be required to make sure the pieces are delivered at an appropriate time. The effort to do these tasks would need to be accounted for somewhere. For organizations that are trying to be lean or agile, they would try to establish cross-functional teams that could carry out the changes to both the API and the UI at the same time within a single team and would therefore estimate (if they were even estimating - there are better alternatives to estimation) the work as a single unit.

Comment: So that’s what I’m thinking really… interns of branching then… would they work on separate branches or one branch with the whole functionality?

Answer (score 0):

In real life you estimate your work and say you have a dependencies on another team.

Then the politics start.

In theory though the other team estimate and schedule their work and you get both an estimate of work, and an expected delivery date